# Prevent validation on update

Tags: php, yii, yii2

How can I prevent validation when record is being updated? I need to prevent it from validating email, password and password confirm. This are current rules:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'password_confirm'], 'required'],
            [['role_id', 'state_id', 'country_id', 'zip'], 'integer'],
            [['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'address', 'city'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['password', 'password_confirm'], 'string', 'min' => 8],

            ['password_confirm', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'password'],
            ['email', function($attribute) {
                $user = static::findOne(['email' => Yii::$app->encrypter->encrypt($this->{$attribute})]);
                if ($user) {
                    $this->addError($attribute, 'This email is already in use.');
                }
            }],
            ['email', 'email'],

        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sasha why would you want to prevent validation on update? That is bad practice however, if you would want to have it your way your code become:

First you would need to create a scenario in your model

```
namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class {YourClass} extends ActiveRecord
{
  /** Other stuff above */

public function scenarios(){

  $scenarios = parent::scenarios(); 
  $scenarios['update'] = ['!email', '!password', '!password_confirm'];

 return $scenarios;
 }


public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['first_name', 'last_name'], 'required'],
            [['email', 'password', 'password_confirm'], 'safe', 'on'=>'update'],
            [['role_id', 'state_id', 'country_id', 'zip'], 'integer'],
            [['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'address', 'city'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['password', 'password_confirm'], 'string', 'min' => 8],

            ['password_confirm', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'password'],
            ['email', function($attribute) {
                $user = static::findOne(['email' => Yii::$app->encrypter->encrypt($this->{$attribute})]);
                if ($user) {
                    $this->addError($attribute, 'This email is already in use.');
                }
            }],
            ['email', 'email'],

        ];
    }
```

Then set the scenario in `actionUpdate()` using the `setScenario('update)` method.

Comment: Email is used as unique login info, and because of this it can't be updated. Password update will be handled via separate form. Because of this I need to remove email and password validation on update.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent validation of specific attributes on specific actions you can define `except` parameter.
E.g:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //some rules ...
            ['password_confirm', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'password', 'except'=>['update']],
            [['password', 'password_confirm'], 'required', 'except'=>['update']]
            //some rules ...
        ];
    }
```

And then in your update action when you instantiate new model, just set scenario to *update* `$model->scenario = 'update'`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use core event: beforeValidate. You can read about it [here](http://pritomkumar.blogspot.com/2013/06/yii-use-beforesave-and-beforevalidate.html)